# android eclipse emulator device not run

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am new to android, my emulator is not working. I installed eclipse.exe file in the following location:  D:\uni course software\android\eclipse

Below is the error i get when launching the emulator:

```
Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
 Performing com.example.loginpg.LoginpgActivity activity launch
 Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'fyp'
 Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'fyp'
 invalid command-line parameter: course.
 Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have your software in a folder with a space (or multiple spaces).

"D:\uni course software\android\eclipse"

> invalid command-line parameter: course.

Try putting it in a different directory (with no spaces) such as c:\android-dev

Comment: +1. There is also option to make a link (without spaces of course) to the current installation directory and set it as path to sdk in eclipse, but this way emulator will only start from eclipse and won't start from avd manager

Answer (score 0):

Is the AVD running properly? Also, are you sure you have set the Android SDK path correct in Eclipse? I think this is a problem with the emulator installation itself. Check the files inside the tools folder of your android-sdk!

If nothing seems to work, place the SDK in another folder and try using it.

Answer (score 0):

1. A valid Android Virtual Device
2. An Andriod Virtual Device that faied to load . Click 'Details' to see the error.
   Details : Path:c:Userszhangshuzhen.androidavd1.6.avd Target: Android 1.6 (API level 4) Skin: HVGA SD cARD: 256M

Answer (score 0):

Try using Genymotion. You can download a version for Windows/Mac OS X/Linux after registering. A plugin for Eclipse is also avaliable.

i give you link [Genymotion Emulator](http://www.genymotion.com/)  please download and setup.

as per my experience Genymotion Vertual device is faster then android emulator.